# How to find max: value of colorAxis for highMaps drilldown maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highmaps

I have a US map with state drilldowns that are being populated via JSON. How do you set the **max: *value*** for colorAxis to the total number of items in a particular drilldown map.

Right now max: is not set and my colorAxis start at 0 and go up to some random number.

Answer (score 1):

You can set max value on colorAxis

```
colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max:50
},
```

or use tickPositioner and calculate as you need.

```
colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            tickPositioner:function(){
                    console.log(this);
            }
},
```

Docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#colorAxis